# Ubuntu 17.04 [Budgie] GNOME tweak tool; Missing some components

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool, budgie

After successfully install of 17.04, done all updates and so on.
Installed gnome tweak tool. And it missing some components. 
Find some similar issues on website topics but no solution. 
This is how tweak tool looks like:
[image: tweak tool]

There was no errors or any issues from start to finish of any installation in ubuntu
Or is just a issue using budgie?

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what components you are missing.

Comment: What's the problem here?!! I don't see any problem at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks just fine.  The GNOME-Shell specifics have been correctly hidden from the interface.

What is left in the application are the bits and bobs that apply to GNOME without GNOME-Shell i.e. Budgie Desktop.

You should note - GNOME Tweak Tool is written for GNOME-Shell.  For the 10.3 series of Budgie Desktop the application mostly works.

For future versions of Budgie Desktop (v11 and later), GNOME Tweak Tool will not work since most GNOME components will have been removed and rewritten.

Comment: Ah... 
Tweaking with right side panel dosn't give some fair options.
Is there some "tweak tool" for budgie !? Or some nice guide to add/mod it ?!

Comment: somebody will need to help the ubuntu-budgie team to write such a tool.  Similarly, to write a guide.  If you are looking for a specific option that you cannot see in the tool then please create a question.